# Reputation jumps on two days in the midst of little else

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

My [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578925/ronalchn?tab=reputation) appears to have increased for some reason today. I first noticed a jump of 200 reputation on January 18 in just 10 minutes, but assumed it would be soon reversed. I noticed another jump today from votes within a 10 minute time range - just 20 minutes ago, but the previous votes from January 18 still have not been reversed.

I have not answered any questions for weeks, and generally only get some stray votes from old answers.

Is this:

- serial upvoting that doesn't look like serial upvoting to the automated script?
- or something that is not serial upvoting, but looks like serial upvoting to me?

Comment: Don't know why previous upvoting is not reversed but, today's upvotes are obviously serial upvoting.

Comment: The one that just occurred won't even have the chance to get reversed for approximately 23 hours. The one from Jan 18 does look suspicious, though.

Comment: How come no one ever serial upvotes me? :/

Comment: If you feel guilty about this I'm sure we Meta-heads can work it out by mass downvoting you ;-)

Comment: @AustinHenley - you need more answers to get attention

Comment: @Manishearth - downvotes don't reverse upvotes. You can restore the answer score, or the reputation to what it was, but you cannot do both.

Comment: @ronalchn: oh, it was a bad joke :P